# proving something about the infimum distance between 2 set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S,T$ be 2 set. Prove that there is a $x\in S$ s.t, $d(x,T)=d(S,T)$ if $S$ is a compact set. Here, $d(S,T)$ denoted the $\inf\{d(s,t):s\in S, t\in T\}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: A few related/similar questions:
[Continuity of the metric function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48850/continuity-of-the-metric-function), 
[If $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, show $d(A,B)$ is achieved](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109167/if-a-is-compact-and-b-is-closed-show-da-b-is-achieved) 
and 
[Prove that the supremum of the distance between a point in a compact subset and any other subset does not (sic) attain the supremum.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204766/prove-that-the-supremum-of-the-distance-between-a-point-in-a-compact-subset-and)

Comment: is there any way to attack this problem without use of functions, limits etc? Ie is there a way to prove this using concepts of open balls, closed balls, compactness?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S,T$ be subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$. Let $S$ be compact. Let $d(x,T) := \inf_{t \in T} d(x,t)$ and $d(S,T) := \inf_{(s,t) \in S \times T} d(s,t)$.

Claim: There exists $s$ in $S$ such that $d(s,T) = d(S,T)$.

Proof: We have $d(S,T) \leq d(s,T)$ for all $s$ in $S$. Hence it is enough to show that there exists $s$ in $S$ such that $d(S,T) \geq d(s,T)$.

$d(S,T) = \inf_{(s,t) \in S \times T} d(s,t)$ means that for $k$ we can find $(s_k, t_k)$ such that $d(s_k , t_k ) \leq d(S,T) + \frac{1}{k}$. Then  $$ \inf_{t \in T} d(s_k, t) = d(s_k, T) \leq d(S,T) + \frac{1}{k} $$ 
Since $S$ is compact it is sequentially compact hence $s_k$ has a convergent subsequence. Let its limit be denoted by $s$. Then $$\lim_{k \to \infty} d(s_k, T) = d(s,T) \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} d(S,T) + \frac{1}{k} = d(S,T)$$

Which proves the claim.

Comment: You write "Let $s$ denote the limit of $s_n$." Why does $s_n$ converge? And if it does, why should $d(s,T) \leq d(S,T)$? You seem to switch quantifiers in the last sentence: you start with "for each $t \in T$ there is a sequence" and you end up with "there is $s \in S$ such that for all $t$..." (paraphrased). Such an $s$ can't exist in general. You can salvage your approach: try working with two sequences $s_n$, $t_n$ such that $d(s_n,t_n) \to d(S,T)$.

Comment: @commenter Exactly my question too. Why should $d(s,T) \leq d(S,T)$? I discussed the other direction on chat and what appears to be a switching of quantifiers is not. Thanks for the comment, I'll rewrite this later. Maybe.

Comment: Oh, right, it's not switching quantifiers, it's only bad notation: using $s$ for two different things. Confusing.

Comment: @commenter Slave driver : )

Comment: I think I have a correct proof now. Unfortunately, it uses continuity of $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ on the last line which I wanted to avoid. Is there any way to avoid using continuity?

Comment: The definitions and the choice of $(s_k,t_k)$ show that $d(S,T) \leq d(s_k,t_k) \leq d(S,T) +\frac{1}{k}$. Choose integers $k(n) \geq n$ such that $d(s,s_{k(n)}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$ (convergence of some subsequence). Since $k(n) \geq n$ you have $$d(S,T) \leq d(s,t_{k(n)}) \leq d(s,s_{k(n)}) + d(s_{k(n)},t_{k(n)})\leq \frac{1}{n} + d(S,T) + \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} d(S,T),$$
so $d(s,t_{k(n)}) \to d(S,T)$ by the [squeezing lemma](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Squeeze_Theorem). Since $$d(S,T) \leq d(s,T) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} d(s,t_{k(n)}) = d(S,T)$$ this gives $d(s,T) = d(S,T)$.

Comment: @commenter Thank you! That's what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

It smells like homework, so I'll just give a hint: $d(x,T)$ is a continuous function of $x$ (if you don't know it, you need to prove it, of course).

Comment: Let $m = \inf \{ d(s,t) \mid s \in S, t \in T \}$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $(s_n,t_n) \in S \times T$ such that $|d(s_n,t_n)-m|<\varepsilon $. Which means $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(s_n, t_n) = m$. Can we now do $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(s_n, t_n) =  d(s_n,\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n)$? Or how do we get something of the form $d(s_n, T)$? How does one get from the product thing to something only depending on $S$? Thanks.

Comment: @MattN.: It can be tricky to work with limits here, so you are better off working with infima instead. First, we should note a *missing definition* from the above: $d(s,T)=\inf\{d(s,t):t\in T\}$. Now it is clear that $d(s,t)\ge d(S,T)$ always, and therefore $d(s,T)\ge d(S,T)$ as well. So $\inf\{d(s,T):s\in S\}\ge d(S,T)$. We want equality, so we need to show the opposite inequality. To do that, pick any $M>\inf\{d(s,T):s\in S\}$. By definition, there is some $s\in S$ with $d(s,T)<M$. Again from defintions, there is a $t\in T$ with $d(s,t)<M$. And so $d(S,T)<M$.

Comment: (There are still details to be filled in, of course, but I hope the previous comment helps.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me very long to understand, I'm sorry for the late reply. Now I think I understand. Would you mind if I posted a second (full) answer? If you do, I might still post it but shortly after delete it so that only +10k users can see it. But I think I'd benefit from writing it up.

Comment: @MattN.: You're welcome. By all means, write up the full answer. I don't quite see the point of deleting it afterwards, though. Oh, yeah, the homework angle. Well, if you do, then come back and undelete it after a few days. I'm sure you as the author of the answer will be able to do so.

Comment: I've been trying all day to write down something that doesn't use continuity of the metric. Yesterday I thought I had it but I didn't write down the idea and by now I'm convinced it wasn't right. I've read your argument using $M$ several times but still don't understand it. I think I have a (hopefully correct) proof of one direction (the easy one) which I posted as an answer. Unfortunately, I'm stuck for the other direction.